# I dont know why my navigationview click event is not working with navigation view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, navigationview

I cant set onclicklistener for navigationview in this code the menu is working but the menu items in navigation view is not working i have tried in options item selected and navigationitemselected listener too but its not working i have set the id in menu item and id in nav graph same but its not working

```
 package com.nads.epicureapp

 import android.content.Context
 import android.content.res.Configuration
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.util.Log
 import android.view.Menu
 import android.view.MenuItem
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupWithNavController

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.nads.epicureapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{




private lateinit var appBarConfiguration : AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var navController:NavController
private lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var toolbar:Toolbar
private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
private lateinit var drawerLayout:DrawerLayout
private lateinit var navView:NavigationView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    toolbar = binding.root!!.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentactivatedformain) as NavHostFragment

    navController = navHostFragment.navController
    drawerLayout = binding.root!!.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    navView = binding.root!!.findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.homeFragment,R.id.profilePage,R.id.settings_dest),drawerLayout)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,appBarConfiguration)


}






override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu)
    return true
}





override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentactivatedformain) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}




override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.profilePage-> {
            Log.e("NAV","nav selected working")
            binding.root.findNavController().navigate(R.id.profilePage)
            return true
        }
        else->
        {
            return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

    }
    }

  // return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) ||  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

   }

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    Log.e("NAV","nav selected working2")
    return true
}
}
```

This is the  layout file  for my activity main page

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context="com.nads.epicureapp.MainActivity">
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentactivatedformain"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/userprimary_navigation" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
  </layout>
```

this is my menu items in for navigationview drawerlayout where the profile page id is same as the id of in my navigation graph

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <group android:id="@+id/primary">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profilePage"
        android:icon="@drawable/profileicon"
        android:title="@string/userprofile" />
  </group>
   <item
    android:id="@+id/settings_dest"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_settings"
    android:title="@string/settings" />

   </menu>
```

this is my navgraph which i use to navigate to the profile page in this navigation graph

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/userprimary_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Epicure App"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_searchFoods"
        app:destination="@id/searchFoods" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_searchCooks"
        app:destination="@id/searchCooks" />
   </fragment>
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/cooksPage"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.CooksPage"
    android:label="Cooks Page"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cooks_page" />
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/searchFoods"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.SearchFoods"
    android:label="Serch foods"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search_foods" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_searchFoods_to_foodDetails"
        app:destination="@id/foodDetails" />
   </fragment>
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/searchCooks"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.SearchCooks"
    android:label="Serch Cooks"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search_cooks" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_searchCooks_to_cooksPage"
        app:destination="@id/cooksPage" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/addRecipes"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.AddRecipes"
    android:label="Add Recipes"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_recipes" />
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/settings_dest"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.Settings"
    android:label="Settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/foodDetails"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.FoodDetails"
    android:label="fragment_food_details"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_details" />
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/profilePage"
    android:name="com.nads.epicureapp.ui.homepage.ProfilePage"
    android:label="fragment_profile_page"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile_page" />
    </navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **when** in **onNavigationItemSelected** as below

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
 when(item.itemId){
    R.id.youritemid-> {
        Log.e("NAV","nav selected working")
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: How you are checking it is working or not? Try a Toast too.

Comment: the log.e() value is not showing and the page is not opening

Comment: I got the answer the problem was in my activity main layout i have to put the navigation view content at the end below my linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the answer the problem is we should put our navigation view after the linear layout component inside the drawerlayout after all the content views at the end of the drawerLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context="com.nads.epicureapp.MainActivity">
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentactivatedformain"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/userprimary_navigation" />
 </LinearLayout>
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu"
app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```